# FrameLayout : Fill empty space

Tags: android, android-layout

I have 3 `FrameLayout` in my layout, the first and the third have a fixed height (wrap_content of child views).

And I want the second `FrameLayout` to fill remaining space between the first and the third element.

My XML :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/root"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <!-- ... childs views with fixed height -->
</FrameLayout>

<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp" <!-- Fill remaining space -->
    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp" >

    <!-- ... childs views with match_parent height -->
</FrameLayout>

<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <!-- ... childs view with fixed height -->
</FrameLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Its better to use `RelativeLayout` as parent in this scenario.

Comment: Can you explain me why ?

Comment: If you use a `RelativeLayout`, you can declare the 0dp FrameLayout as the LAST ONE and give it `match_parent`, to fill the remaining height.

Comment: You can do the same with `FrameLayout`, please have a look to the @blackbelt answer :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can use the `layout_weight="1"` property for the central `FrameLayout`, leaving `0dip` for the `height`. It will the take the space left from the other two

Comment: Android Studio complains "Nested weights are bad for performance".
Is there any other solution?

Comment: You could try ConstraintLayout with the four constraints start/end/top/bottom set to parent. That is only a warning in the end